# Time complexity of range query

Tags: time-complexity

I'm trying to learn about time complexities of different search data structures. I pretty much understand search, insertion and deletion, but what I don't get is a range query. For example, what would be the range query time complexities for unordered and ordered linked lists, or unbalanced and balanced bin trees (or AVL), or then for hash tables? I've found the bigocheatsheet.com site, but they don't seem to say anything about range queries.

Also about the basic search and insertion, how does it change things when a hash table is half full with say quadratic probing? A perfect hash function would make things constant but what about when it's not perfect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range query means finding all elements that falls within a given range. For example a range query of [a,b] on a data structure would mean to find count of elements that fall in between a and b.

Serving a range query on an ordered or unordered link list will require O(n) time because in worst case you need to traverse the entire list to look for elements a and b.

Serving a range query on an balanced or unbalanced binary tree requires the same worst case time O(n) unless the tree is [Range Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree). If it is a [Range Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree) then range query takes O(logn, k) where k is the number of elements in that range.

In short the worst case time complexity for range query is O(n) unless the data structure is specially augmented with information that makes the range query faster. To optimize a data structure for range queries first some preprocessing is done on the dataset and necessary info is stored with each node. At the time of serving the range query the info stored at each node is used to reduce the search scope.